# Matplotlib keeps installing into pyshared folder

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext3, anaconda

Matplotlib keeps installing into `/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/matplotlib/`
from which I can't access it from Sublime Text 3.
I get: `ImportError: No module named matplotlib`

Any ideas how I can redirect the installation into `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`? I keep trying to install with `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` but I also tried `pip install matplotlib` and Sublime still throws the same error.

Comment: How are you "accessing it" from Sublime?

Comment: Obviously. How are you running the file - through a build system? Which version of Python is it using?

Comment: I tried crl+b in Sublime and also python <filename> from the terminal. Same ImportError in both situations. If my file is print 'Hello World' instead both ways work fine. 'which python' command resulted in  /home/mariusz/anaconda/bin/python.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22321879/1461210).